# MBProgressHUD delegate hudWasHidden not called

Tags: ios, mbprogresshud

I use MBProgressHUD in my iPhone app. Everything works fine, I display alerts as I want. But there's an issue : I can't use the `hudWasHidden` delegate for one of my alerts. I want to do this because I use a custom segue to load a view from another, but I want to load the view only after the alert hid. I call the alert that way : `[alertSentHUD hide:YES afterDelay:2.0];` and I've set my class to be a `MBProgressHUDDelegate` (in the header file). I also put `[alertSentHUD setDelegate:self];` in my viewDidLoad, in order to catch the `hudWasHidden` in question, where I launch my segue as I usually do : `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NewAlertToAllThreads" sender:self];`.

But it seems like this is never called (I don't get to the view I want).

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever there is no message / no action as expected. It means that something is nil. 
Check whether before calling [alertSentHUD setDelegate:self] whether alertSentHud contains nil or not .

Aso make sure that you set the delegate before you pass a message hide to your MBProgressHUD . 
I mean make sure that [alertSentHUD hide:YES afterDelay:2.0] is called after you set the delegate.

Comment: That was it ! In fact, my MBProgressHUD was part of my class (declared in the @interface). I was trying to set the delegate in viewDidLoad, but the MBProgressHUD was only initialized later in an other function. I moved the setDelegate:self after the HUD is initialized, and it solved the problem. One last question : I only tried the second part of your answer (move the setDelegate), how can I check "whether alertSentHud contains nil or not" ? Thanks !

Comment: The most easy way out there is to print using NSlog statement . But it is always advisable  to check boundary conditions using if statements / assertions in your code

Answer (score 1):

Even if you put an `NSLog()` into `hudWasHidden:` it will not shown? Nonetheless more source code would be great to understand you issue. You can also try to use the blocks methods:

```
[self doSomethingInBackgroundWithProgressCallback:^(float progress) {
    hud.progress = progress;
} completionCallback:^{
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NewAlertToAllThreads" sender:self];
}];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but Kunal Balani solved my issue.